# Differences between following sentences

Tags: grammar

What are the 'meanings' and the'differences' between following sentences:

1. He **might not** be cooking.
2. He **could not** be cooking.
3. He **wouldn't** be cooking.

Answer (score 3):

1. He **might not** be cooking.
   This shows that there's a **remote** posibility for him not to be cooking.
2. He **could not** be cooking.
   This refers to ability. It confirms that in the continuous frame, he didn't have the ability to do so.
3. He **would not** be cooking.
   This implies a present conditional situation. It's often connected with a counterfactual situation. For instance: *he **wouldn't** be cooking* (*if I told him / if I wanted to*, etc).

Answer (score 0):

1. It is uncertain whether he is cooking.

> "He is a really good chef, but he might not be cooking tonight. It
>   might be his wife."

2. It is certain he is not cooking.

> "The oven is broken. He could not be cooking."

3. Some event or circumstance stops him from cooking.

> "He would't be cooking. He is lazy."

The words you show in bold would be somewhat emphasised in speech.

I am British.

Comment: @ Anthony Scaife,what do you mean by 3rd sentence'wouldn't be cooking, what kind of circumstances and is it imagined situation? please provide contextual examples to make me understand it.